# How make Bottombar with custom shape fab button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar, bottombar

I want to make a bottombar with attach fab button like given below image. If anyone knows about that type of different shape button library with a bottom with fab then suggest to me.

The image is given below make a bottombar with fab like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is just an idea the code can be improved.
You can change the shape of the `FloatingActionButton` with the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/cutfab"
    ..>
```

with:

```
<style name="cutfab">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">15dp</item>
</style>
```

Then you can define the `BottomAppBar` in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="14dp"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp" />
```

Finally you can apply to the `BottomAppBar` a **`TopEdgeTreatment`**. Something like:

```
BottomAppBar bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment topEdge = new BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge(
        bar.getFabCradleMargin(),
        bar.getFabCradleRoundedCornerRadius(),
        bar.getCradleVerticalOffset());
MaterialShapeDrawable babBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bar.getBackground();

babBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
  babBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
  .toBuilder()
  .setTopEdge(topEdge)
  .build());
```

[image]

Where the `BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge` is something like:

```
public class BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge extends BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment {

    private final float fabMargin;
    private final float cradleVerticalOffset;

    BottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge(
            float fabMargin, float roundedCornerRadius, float cradleVerticalOffset) {
        super(fabMargin, roundedCornerRadius, cradleVerticalOffset);
        this.fabMargin = fabMargin;
        this.cradleVerticalOffset = cradleVerticalOffset;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("RestrictTo")
    public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation, ShapePath shapePath) {
        float fabDiameter = getFabDiameter();
        if (fabDiameter == 0) {
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return;
        }

        float diamondSize = fabDiameter / 2f;
        float middle = center + getHorizontalOffset();

        float verticalOffsetRatio = cradleVerticalOffset / diamondSize;
        if (verticalOffsetRatio >= 1.0f) {
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return;
        }

        shapePath.lineTo(middle - (fabMargin + diamondSize), 0);    
        shapePath.lineTo(middle - fabDiameter/3, (diamondSize - cradleVerticalOffset + fabMargin) * interpolation);    
        shapePath.lineTo(middle + fabDiameter/3, (diamondSize - cradleVerticalOffset + fabMargin) * interpolation);    
        shapePath.lineTo(middle + (fabMargin + diamondSize), 0);    
        shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
    }

}
```

To obtain a better result you should extend the `CutCornerTreatment`, implementing in the `getCornerPath` method the same path used in the `BottomAppBar` and apply it to the `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use latest style BottomAppBar in your app.

**1)** Include Google Maven repository in build.gradle.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
   }
  }
}
```

**2)** Place material components dependency in your `build.gradle`. Keep in mind that
material version is regularly updating.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

**3)**  Make sure your app inherits `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme in order to make BottomAppBar use the latest style. Alternatively you can declare the style for BottomAppBar in widget declaration within layout xml file as follows.

```
style=”@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar”
```

You can include BottomAppBar in your layout as follows. BottomAppBar must be a child of CoordinatorLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
app:fabAttached="true"
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_white_24"/>
```

You can anchor a Floating Action Button (FAB) to BottomAppBar by specifying the id of the BottomAppBar in `app:layout_anchor` attribute of the FAB. BottomAppBar can cradle FAB with a shaped background or FAB can overlap BottomAppBar.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />
```

**THANKS**

Comment: Yes thank you. We already know how to add `BottomAppBar` to the layout (And also there is a [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bars/)) but the OP is asking about `BottomAppBar` **with a different shape & look!**