# How would I be able to "cut out" a circular shape for a fab button in my ui background?

Tags: android, user-interface, background-image, android-drawable

[image: What I'm trying to go for]

I'm trying to achieve the same as what's boxed in the image only I'm a programmer and I'm not sure how to start.

Could this be achieved with a drawable? If so, would yo be able to point me in the right direction, or is it much more complex and something a graphics designer would need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using the help of **Material BottomAppBar** along with **Floating Action Button(FAB)**. You need to simply place both of them under the `NestedScrollView` of the layout which is shown below

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Note: A RecyclerView can also be used -->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <!-- Scrollable content -->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Set these attributes accordingly to achieve the shape what you want. Use `fabCradleMargin` and `fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius` attributes in `BottomAppBar` to set the rounded Corner and margin.

Kindly [refer](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom/android#anatomy-and-key-properties) to the official documentation for more information about implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a basic knowledge of how to create custom `Path` in Android using code or XML
I would suggest not doing something like this, before learning about the same

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62889050/9722336) is a similar build up that can help you